# Blackberry Can I view contents of .cod file?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

Got a .jad and a bunch of .cod files.  Can I view the contents of the .cod files?  Thanks

Comment: Is there any way to view the source from this?

Answer (score 1):

.cod files are basically .jar files that have been processed through RIM's compilation tool chain.  Additionally RIM tools strip some information from the .jar files before cod-ifying them and if the size is too big, it splits and zips the pieces.  So if you have a bunch of .cod files for the same .jad file you should first try unzipping them using a standard zip program then join them using some concat utility and finally try using a .jar file decompiler to see if you can hack the byte code.  That is pretty much your best bet.

Comment: Have you ever successfully been able to view the contents of the resulting .jar file? Even if you couldn't decompile the .classes with in?

Comment: I remember viewing the contents of a single .cod file i.e. when my project was small enough that only one .cod was produced from it.  However, I heard that RIM have changed a few things around since then.